# Indexing array in python results in lost scientific notation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3 column numpy array (named `data`) that looks something like this:

```
[ "names",    floating point #1,    floating point #2,
  "names",    floating point #1,    floating point #2,
  "names",    floating point #1,    floating point #2,
  "names",    floating point #1,    floating point #2,
  "names",    floating point #1,    floating point #2,
  "names",    floating point #1,    floating point #2 ]
```

where everything is actually of type String. I'm trying to select the rows that have floating point #2 less than 20. I first extract the 3rd column, convert it to an array of Floats (with `dataFloat = data3rdcol.astype("float")`), and then index the rows in `data` with `dataParsed = data[dataFloat<20,:]`.

This extracts the rows I want, but in the process it strips off the exponential notation of the floating point numbers (6.7444e-6 becomes 6.7444). This ruins the data set, and I need it to stop. Any ideas?

Comment: This is just a printing issue, the data is same.

Comment: Cannot duplicate.
`>>> a = numpy.array(['1e-6', '1e6'])`
`>>> a[a.astype('float')<20]`
`array(['1e-6'], `
`dtype='|S4')`

Comment: It's not just a printing issue, as the value 6.7444 is indeed added into my dataset.

Comment: What is your reason for using strings in the first place? What version of Numpy are you using (works in 1.8.1)?

Comment: Turns out there wasn't actually a problem, I was just misreading a value. Sorry to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string is "6.7444e-6", just float(s) :

```
f = float(s)
f
6.7444e-06
```